# ApexCharts only shows 5 labels (type datetime)

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I have a chart with one value per day. Somehow it only labels 5 days on the x-axis.
How can I make it label all the days between the set min and max date (as far as I know tickAmount does not work with type datetime)?

And how can I remove the offset on the x-axis so that the point for every day is directly above its label (See offset here)?

[image: 1]

```js
var options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Series1',
        data: [
            5, 6, 5.5, 7, 1, 3, 4
        ]
    }],
    chart: {
        height: 250,
        type: 'area'
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth'
    },
    colors:['#000000'],
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: [
            '2022-07-20 00:00:00', '2022-07-21 00:00:00', '2022-07-22 00:00:00', '2022-07-23 00:00:00', '2022-07-24 00:00:00', '2022-07-25 00:00:00', '2022-07-26 00:00:00'
        ],
        min: new Date("2022-07-20 00:00:00").getTime(),
        max: new Date("2022-07-26 00:00:00").getTime(),
        labels: {
            formatter: function(val) {
                return moment(new Date(val)).format("ddd");
            },
            style: {
                colors: '#000000',
            },
            datetimeUTC: false, // Do not convert to UTC
        },
    },
    yaxis: {
        labels: {
            style: {
                colors: '#000000',
            },
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val.toFixed(0)
            },
        },
        tickAmount: 10,
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
};

document.getElementById("chart").innerHTML = "";
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

</body>
</html>

<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Comment: Remove that `min` and `max` attributes in `xaxis` and see what happens.

Comment: @CuriousMind that does not change anything... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution for the problems you mention, we removed the tags:

- **type** inside xaxis
- **min** and **max**

We add the **tickAmount** tag with value 6 (7 ticks 0-6).

Another problem detected has been the value of the labels since 5.5 rounded it to 6, so that it does not happen we add it inside the **tooltip** label

```
y: {
  formatter: function (val) {
    return val.toFixed(1);
  }
}
```

I leave the solution in react below.

[CodeSandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-khayyam-8mfry7?file=/src/GraphicLine.jsx)

Result of the solution in photo
[image: graph showing the 7 labels]